# Spinner on clicking an item in DetailsList

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How do I show a spinner in a DetailsList? For instance,  let's say I have the following items in a DetailsList:

[list of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siCiz.jpg)

On clicking the item with the name 'AdipiscingUt.onetoc', show a spinner on the rightmost side of that item (next to 125 KB). Please let me know if you have any suggestions on the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selection` attribute in `<DetailsList>` component to catch the selection events. Then create extra column with hidden `spinner` and display it via `selection` event.

At least I had the experience when I needed to display the icon status according to each item. I added unique id per each item (using `onRender` method for `columns` attribute in `<DetailsList>`) and use it for identification.